# In oracle how to retrieve users who has @gmail extension mails from email column from user table

Tags: sql, oracle

I need the oracle query to retrieve users who has @gmail extension mails from email column from users table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from users where email like '%@gmail%'
```

Answer (score 0):

- Use `LOWER` (or `UPPER`) to ensure that you match case.
- Don't put a wild card at the end of the `LIKE` match as otherwise you will match valid e-mails such as `myaddress@gmail.com.example.com`.
- GMail e-mails can use the `gmail.com` and `googlemail.com` domains interchangably; you may need to match both.

Like:

```
SELECT *
FROM   users
WHERE  LOWER( email ) LIKE '%@gmail.com'
OR     LOWER( email ) LIKE '%@googlemail.com'
```